# Regular behaviour on run app from Android Studio. Weid behaviour on apk

Tags: android, android-studio, build, apk, build-process

The Environment.name method is used multiple times in my application:

```
public class Environment {
    public static final int PRODUCTION = 0;
    public static final int TRAINING = 1;
    public static final int TEST = 2;
    public static final int DEV = 3;

    public static final int CURRENT_ENV = TEST;

    public static String text(Activity activity) {
        // Code which sets version ... Irrelevant to the question ...

        return name() + " " + version;
    }

    public static String name() {
        switch (CURRENT_ENV) {
            case PRODUCTION:
                return "Production";
            case TRAINING:
                return "Training";
            case TEST:
                return "Test";
            case DEV:
                return "Development";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

When I run the project on Android Studio 1.2.1.1 (Shift + F10), the string returned from the name method respect the CURRENT_ENV value.

When I generate a signed apk (Build -> Generate Signed APK ...) and install it on my tablet, the name returned from name does not respect the CURRENT_ENV value.

For example:

```
public static final int CURRENT_ENV = TEST;
```

Environment.name() returns "Training".

It seems to be a bug on build the apk. How could I fix it?

Comment: _"the name returned from name does not respect the CURRENT_ENV value"_ How do you know that ? i.e. did you check the value of CURRENT_ENV with a log or your debugger ?

Comment: The returned value is inserted in a TextView.

Comment: I was talking about the value of the int CURRENT_ENV

Comment: I know it does not respect the value of CURRENT_ENV because name() returns the wrong value ... But i'll log it anyway.

Comment: It was a damn cache in my webserver where i store my apks. Thanks!